# Payment system process in other country

Tags: api, paypal, payment

I am a Korean developer.

I want to know other countries payment system.
Korea has various plugin and complicated process to buy somethings but in Digital ocean or Amazon, and these kind of every site's payment system needs just a card number and it makes the automatically dealing things.

What makes this kind of process too simple to do that?
Also, those systems automatically verify the card number like VISA, MASTER or else.
Did the global financial companies have any "payment API systems"?

I wonder if I can use that process or algorithm in Korea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [How PayPal Works](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ2385) and get some idea how their system works.

PayPal is not allowed to verify automatically the card number of any VISA, MASTER, Etc.. because it's a security risk. *-"Keeping the PIN in their database?"*

PayPal is like a mobile SIM card you need to load it first to make text and call. The difference is PayPal allowed the user to use email address or mobile number to purchase item online to any website that allowed PayPal purchase. *-"of course with privileged of the owner"*

Please visit [Developer PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/) for more information.